# How can I use the HtmlEncode (or HtmlDecode) function in Visual Studio (vb.net)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, html-encode

I'm making an application that involves logging into a server, however, the post data needs some encoding.

```
Dim strEncUsername As String = Server.HtmlEncode(Me.txtUsername.Text)
```

However, since this isn't an asp.net application, this doesn't work. How the hay am I supposed to do this? I tried looking for an Imports thing, but no real luck.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you add a reference to System.Web to your project you can use the following to html encode your string

```
Dim strEncUsername As String = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Me.txtUsername.Text)
```

[MSDN Documentation for HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx)

**Edit**
Screenshot of intellisense showing HtmlEncode:
[image: Screenshot of intellisense showing HtmlEncode]

Screenshot of references in project:
[image: Screenshot of references in project]

Output from application:

```
unsafe text: <em>evil em tags within</em>
safe text: &lt;em&gt;evil em tags within&lt;/em&gt;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. (most common problem ever for any coder).

'HTTPUtility' is not a member of 'Web'.

I'm using VS 2008. Is this a new member of the System.web namespace? It shouldn't be.

Comment: @AustinBurk, it has been part of System.web since at least .Net Framework 1.1 according to MSDN. You've definitely referenced the right DLL? I'll create a quick console app to test myself.

Comment: This stupid comment thing doesn't want to give me line breaks.

Pretty sure.

(earlier in code:

    Imports System.Web

later in code:

    Dim strEncUsername As String = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Me.txtUsername.Text)

Comment: @AustinBurk have you added a reference to the project though...as in Project \ Add Reference (Browser to System.Web)

Comment: Aha! Problem solved. Thanks! Now all I have to do is find my muffin recipe. Mmm.

Answer (score 7):

System.web is not available in NET 4.0 client profile... I wonder why.

It can't even be added as a reference.

But the same thing can be accomplished by using:

System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode

Comment: Thanks, I JUST did this like a month ago and already forgot, but you have it right.  For 4.0+ you need System.Net.WebUtility.  I'm glad, I have completely removed System.Web from my web applications.  It's all System.Net

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use [`HttpUtility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) (add reference to System.Web first).

Answer (score 1):

In a Windows application you can also use:

```
    System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode
```

providing the Framework version is 4 or above, see: [link]https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388364(v=vs.110).aspx